# Redefining chapter conflicts with acronyms in memoir

Tags: macros, memoir, acronyms

I redefined `\chapter*` but when I use acronyms from the `glossaries` package, I get a bunch of errors. A minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{acronym_file}

\makeatletter
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\renewcommand*\chapter{%
    \if@star{\starchapter}{\stdchapter}
\def\starchapter[#1]#2{%
    \stdchapter*[{#1}]{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

This gives me the error message `! Use of \starchapter doesn't match its definition.`

If I remove `\printacronyms` or if I use `\printglossary` instead of `\printacronyms`, I don't get the error message.

Also, if I replace `\def\starchapter[#1]#2{\stdchapter*[{#1}]{#2}}` by `\newcommand*\starchapter[1]{\stdchapter*{#1}}`, I don't get the error message (note that this doesn't work for me, since I want the optional parameter in `\chapter[foo]{bar}`)

Is there a (hopefully easy) way to change my chapter definition so that I don't get this problem with acronyms?

Comment: Your `\starchapter` doesn't have an *optional* argument with square brackets but a *mandatory* one because you defined it with `\def`. You'd want to do `\newcommand*\startchapter[2][]{... #1 is optional and #2 is mandatory ... }`

Comment: There's another issue here: `memoir` provides `\chapter[][]{}`, i.e. with two optional arguments

Comment: @ChristianHupfer only in the unstarred variant IIRC. There are more things: there's a closing brace missing, `\if@star` is undefined (it's `\@ifstar`) and the redefinition `\renewcommand*\chapter{\@ifstar{\starchapter}{\chapter}}` used as `\chapter{foo}` causes and endless loop…

Comment: @clemens: True, but the heading `[...]` argument is for the starred available too

Comment: what is the goal of the redefinition? If your redefinition were working it just calls the original `\chapter` with the same arguments… this seems kind of pointless.

Comment: @clemens In my document, the redefinition does several things, but in order to make a MWE, I removed everything that didn't remove the error.

Comment: @usernumber: I provided a redefinition (useless, however, since it does the same as not redefining it -- the real change must be entered by you then)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the real change doesn't seem to be causing any problems, so I removed it to make the question more generic. I did think your answer was very interesting though before it was deleted.

Comment: @usernumber: It was useless to you, apparently

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I found another solution before seeing yours, but yours was useful in helping me understand how `\chapter` works and how to redefine it without using `\makeatletter\let...`. Also, it could have been useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that works:

```
\makeatletter
\let\stdchapter\chapter
\renewcommand*\chapter{%
    \if@star{\@dblarg\starchapter}{\stdchapter}
\def\starchapter[#1]#2{%
    \stdchapter*[{#1}]{#2}}
\makeatother
```

This seems to do the trick (though I'm not so sure it's the best way to do things given the comments by clemens and Christian Hupfer)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `\NewDocumentCommand` to check for the multiple cases:

`\chapter[][]{}`

and `\chapter*[]{}`

Fill in the new definitions of your own chapter - style then.

My definition here will fail for `\chapter*[][]{}` -> what should be done there?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeglossaries
%\loadglsentries{acronym_file}

\newacronym{LaTeX}{\LaTeX}{LaTeX is fun}

\makeatletter
\let\stdchapter\chapter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{soom}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% Is it starred -> yes, so check for #2.
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \stdchapter*[#2]{#4}% -> #2 is heading title 
    }{%
      \stdchapter*{#4}%     
    }%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \IfValueTF{#3}{%
        \stdchapter[#2][#3]{#4}% -> #2 is toc title, #3 is head title
      }{%
        \stdchapter[#2]{#4}% No head title #3
      }%
    }{%
      % Do not check for #3 since #2 isn't here!
      \stdchapter{#4}%     
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}

\chapter[Another one]{Second}

\chapter[Yet Another one][My nice title]{Third}

\gls{LaTeX}

\chapter*{Not in Toc}

\chapter*[Head of unnumbered chapter]{Also not in toc}



\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't need `\LetLtxMacro` I believe. `\chapter` itself does not have any arguments whatsoever

Comment: @clemens: Yes, it's a moving one. I'll keep it anyway

Comment: `\chapter` has *no* arguments – moving or not (check with `\show\chapter`). If you were to copy the internal `\@m@mchapter` then `\LetLtxMacro` would help avoiding `\\@m@mchapter`

Comment: @clemens: Alright, alright, I removed `\LetLtxMacro`